# how to delete string from text file and save as same file?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash function to delete a garbage string (including the quotation marks and parentheses) from a text file and resave the file with the same filename.

I got it to work when I save it as a new file...

```
function fixfile()
{
sed 's/(\"garbagestringhere\")//g' /Users/peter/.emacs.d/recent-addresses > /Users/peter/.emacs.d/recent-addresses-fixed;
}
```

...but when I save it with the same filename as before, it wipes the file:

```
function fixfile()
{
sed 's/(\"garbagestringhere\")//g' /Users/peter/.emacs.d/recent-addresses > /Users/peter/.emacs.d/recent-addresses;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GNU sed `man sed` will reveal the `-i` option:

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

          edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

If you are on OSx (or BSD) you can employ ([see this reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573368/in-place-edits-with-sed-on-os-x))

```
sed -i '' 's/whatever//g' file
//    ^ note the space
```

Comment: `function fixfile()
{
sed -i 's/(\"garbagestringhere\")//g' /Users/peter/.emacs.d/recent-addresses > /Users/peter/.emacs.d/recent-addresses;
}` gives me `sed: 1: "/Users/peter/.emacs.d/rec ...": invalid command code j`

Comment: Do not use the output redirect `>` anymore. Just use `sed -i 'expr' INPUT_FILE`

Comment: `sed -i 's/(\"garbagestringhere\")//g' /Users/peter/.emacs.d/recent-addresses` still gives me `sed: 1: "/Users/peter/.emacs.d/rec ...": invalid command code j``

Comment: What OS and sed version are you running? Try `sed --version`. You are probably on OSx right?

Comment: Yes, I'm on OSX. `$ sed --version
sed: illegal option -- -
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]`

Answer (score 1):

Even if in your particular case I suggest the use of **`sed -i`**,
in a more general approach you can consider the use of **[*sponge*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge)** 
from moreutils.

```
sed '...' file | grep '...' | awk '...' | sponge file
```

> Sponge reads standard input and writes it out to the specified file. Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before opening the output file. This allows constricting pipelines that read from and write to the same file.
>   If no output file is specified, sponge outputs to stdout

(Git from [here](http://repo.or.cz/w/moreutils.git), or from [here](https://github.com/madx/moreutils/blob/master/debian/control)...)

Alternatively you can use a **temporary file** that you delete before you exit from your function.
Temporary file with a **random (or pseudorandom) [namefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793812/generate-a-random-filename-in-unix-shell)**.