# Create a random file on linux using dd and /dev/random

Tags: linux, random, dd

I executed this:

```
$ dd if=/dev/random of=foo bs=1G count=1
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
6 bytes (6 B) copied, 0.00016958 s, 35.4 kB/s

$ stat -c "%s" foo
6
```

Also this does not work, I get stuck in the command:

```
$ head -c 500 /dev/random > foo
```

What is my mistake?

I'm on Linux mint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a random filename in unix shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793812/generate-a-random-filename-in-unix-shell)

Comment: This question was not about the filename but the content. Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/dev/random wil just deliver random data until the entropy sources for the RNG are exhausted. If you want to read bigger chunks of (pseudo-)random data, you can read from /dev/urandom instead.

Comment: `/dev/urandom` is very very slow. It takes about 1minute to generate about 30MB. Is it normal?

Comment: Is it possible to generate `bad random` file quickly? I just wanna get a dummy file to benchmark a file transfer over nfs.

Comment: For that purpose, it should be sufficient to create a smaller file and concatenat that a couple of times to create a larger one: dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=1024 >1m; cat 1m 1m 1m 1m 1m >5m; cat 5m 5m 5m 5m 5m >25m; cat 25m 25m 25m 25m>100m

Comment: That should indeed work for NFS. To generate test data for tools that are harder to fool like `rsync` or `xz`, you can use `head -c 100m /dev/zero | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -pass pass:"$(head -c 20 /dev/urandom | base64)"  > my100MBfile`.